# Python: Decrypting a file (have key)

Tags: python, string, list, file, encryption

I encrypted a file from ascii randomized key. I need to decrypt back into normal letters from and then put that into a new file

```
import random

lst = list(range(1,128)) #for key
numbersran = list()

while len(numbersran) < 128:      
    candidate = random.randint(1,128)
    if candidate not in numbersran:
        numbersran.append(candidate) 

listsdict = dict(zip(lst,numbersran)) #makes key, changes every time
print("Encytption key=", listsdict)
print()

filename=input("Enter File: ")
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    filetxt = file.read()
    ascii_codes = [ord(c) for c in filetxt]

encrypted_codes = [listsdict[code] for code in ascii_codes]
print('\nEncrypted file: ',encrypted_codes)
cypher = "".join([chr(c) for c in encrypted_codes])    #encrypts from key

#decrypt below here into a file using the key to translate (should be original text from file)
```

I am not too sure how to reverse the process back to the original text in file. Must be decrypted back, can't just be copied from og file

Comment: Use a reversed `listsdict`, swapping keys & values.

Comment: i completely forgot about this. I remember thinking that that was the solution but completely forgot about trying it

Answer (score 0):

The decryption process should be reverse of what has been done for encryption. Find below the code snippet.

```
decrypted_file = [ord(c) for c in cypher]
decrypted_key = list()
for value in decrypted_file:
    for key in listsdict:
        if listsdict[key] == value:
            decrypted_key.append(key)
            break
print(''.join([chr(c) for c in decrypted_key]))
```

There can be better ways to achieve the decryption but the solution in its naivest form should be like above.

easy way to replace this code snippet:

```
for value in decrypted_file:
    for key in listsdict:
        if listsdict[key] == value:
            decrypted_key.append(key)
            break
```

is to reverse listsdict keys with value as suggested by @scott hunter

```
decrypted_file = [ord(c) for c in cypher]
decrypted_key = list()
listsdict = dict(zip(numbersran,lst)) 
decrypted_key = [listsdict[code] for code in decrypted_file]
print(''.join([chr(c) for c in decrypted_key]))
```